# How to make a soundpool link with loads of buttons

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, imagebutton, soundpool

I'm making an apps of playing a traditional music instruments. The user has to follow the song note, and the marks will be calculated after he finishes played the song. The problem is how to calculate the marks because the song notes are very long.

I'm using **soundPool** to produce the sound.

This is the screenshot of my app and the coding:

[image]

Help me finishing my final year project.

public class tutorial3 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public Button checkmark;
public static final int ROWS = 2;
public static final int COLS = 5;
public int count = 0;
public int correct = 0;
public boolean a,b,c,d,e;

private SoundPool soundPool;

private AudioManager audioManager;

// Maximumn sound stream.
private static final int MAX_STREAMS = 5;

// Stream type.
private static final int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;

private boolean loaded;

private int soundId1k;
private int soundId2k;
private int soundId3k;
private int soundId5k;
private int soundId6k;
private int soundId1b;
private int soundId2b;
private int soundId3b;
private int soundId5b;
private int soundId6b;
private float volume;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial3);

    //int count = 0;
    // AudioManager audio settings for adjusting the volume
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // Current volumn Index of particular stream type.
    float currentVolumeIndex = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(streamType);

    // Get the maximum volume index for a particular stream type.
    float maxVolumeIndex = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(streamType);

    // Volumn (0 --> 1)
    this.volume = currentVolumeIndex / maxVolumeIndex;

    // Suggests an audio stream whose volume should be changed by
    // the hardware volume controls.
    this.setVolumeControlStream(streamType);

    // For Android SDK >= 21
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

        AudioAttributes audioAttrib = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        SoundPool.Builder builder = new SoundPool.Builder();
        builder.setAudioAttributes(audioAttrib).setMaxStreams(MAX_STREAMS);

        this.soundPool = builder.build();
    }
    // for Android SDK < 21
    else {
        // SoundPool(int maxStreams, int streamType, int srcQuality)
        this.soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    // When Sound Pool load complete.
    this.soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });

    // Load sound file (destroy.wav) into SoundPool.
    this.soundId1k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.one_kecik, 1);

    // Load sound file (gun.wav) into SoundPool.
    this.soundId2k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.two_kecik, 1);

    this.soundId3k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.three_kecik, 1);

    this.soundId5k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.five_kecik, 1);

    this.soundId6k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.six_kecik, 1);

    this.soundId6b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.six_besar, 1);

    this.soundId5b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.five_besar, 1);

    this.soundId3b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.three_besar, 1);

    this.soundId2b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.two_besar, 1);

    this.soundId1b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.one_besar, 1);

    ImageButton btnCells[][] = new ImageButton[ROWS][COLS];
    btnCells[0][0] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn00);
    btnCells[0][1] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn01);
    btnCells[0][2] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn02);
    btnCells[0][3] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn03);
    btnCells[0][4] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn04);
    btnCells[1][0] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn10);
    btnCells[1][1] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn11);
    btnCells[1][2] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn12);
    btnCells[1][3] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn13);
    btnCells[1][4] =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn14);


    boolean push[][] = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];

    push[1][2] = true;
    push[0][2] = true;
    push[1][1] = true;
    push[0][3] = true;
    push[1][0] = true;
    push[0][4] = true;
    push[1][0] = true;
    push[0][4] = true;
    push[1][1] = true;
    push[0][3] = true;
    push[1][2] = true;
    push[0][2] = true;
    push[1][0] = true;
    push[0][4] = true;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {


            if (!push[i][j])
            {
                count++;

            }
        }
    }

    correct = 14 - count;




}


// When users click on the image button
public void playSound1k(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;

        // Play sound objects destroyed. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId1k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}


// When users click on the button "Gun"
public void playSound2k(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId2k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void playSound3k(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId3k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void playSound5k(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId5k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void playSound6k(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId6k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void playSound6b(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId6b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void playSound5b(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId5b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void playSound3b(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId3b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void playSound2b(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId2b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void playSound1b(View view) {
    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        int streamId = this.soundPool.play(this.soundId1b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}

public void chkmarks(View view) {
    checkmark = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chkmark);
    checkmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder altdial = new AlertDialog.Builder(tutorial3.this);
            altdial.setMessage("you scored " + correct + " out of 14!").setCancelable(true)

                    .setNegativeButton("play now!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(tutorial3.this, play.class));
                        }
                    })


                    .setPositiveButton("home", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //dialog.cancel();
                            startActivity(new Intent(tutorial3.this, menu.class));
                        }


                    });




            AlertDialog alert = altdial.create();
            alert.setTitle("Marks");
            alert.show();


        }


    });


}
```

}

Comment: is this Jianpu notation?. How about using List of note coupled with its id and right or wrong boolean value?. You can use a simple pojo for it.

Comment: @isnotmenow Yes it's similar to jianpu notation. Alright I'll try. But is it going to be a very long if else statement?

Comment: Ohh... I got it, yours is not jianpu but number notation like used in Indonesia. you can do it by saving all the note which are presented to user to a list. All note item must have a flag for true or false when user play it. So each step user need to do is the index of the list. Then after user have finished play the song, you just need to calculate the total true or false of the flag.

Comment: yes, it is the indonesian traditional music instruments. I'm sorry for asking, but is there any coding I can refer to? I'm quiet new to this.

Comment: I think you can learn from https://github.com/felixhao28/react-jianpu. Please be note that it's not a java project.

Comment: i have edit the coding by adding array, it works fine however it only calculated the first 4 button that is pressed. Is there any problem with my array?

Comment: it should be error from your code, what is `correct = 14 - count;` doing for?

Comment: to calculate the correct button the user pressed, 14 is the total times they should click

Comment: First, you've a duplicate initialization value for the buttons `push[1][2] = true; push[0][2] = true;`. Second, `correct = 14 - count;` will give you the wrong answer. If you have count 10 `true` answer, then calculate with `correct = 14 - 10`, you will get 4 as the result. that formula should be used to calculate error answers.

Comment: okay i have changed. but sir, i just realized that even if i did not press any button the answer is still generated. Should i add something to make it work? i have clear all the soundpool coding, just left with the imagebutton coding to find the marks

Comment: you only need to calculate after user has finished all the note.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution. here it is

```
  public Button checkmark;
public int count1;
public int sum1;
public int correct;

private SoundPool soundPool;

private AudioManager audioManager;

// Maximumn sound stream.
private static final int MAX_STREAMS = 5;

// Stream type.
private static final int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;

private boolean loaded;

int streamIdd;

private int soundId1k;
private int soundId2k;
private int soundId3k;
private int soundId5k;
private int soundId6k;
private int soundId1b;
private int soundId2b;
private int soundId3b;
private int soundId5b;
private int soundId6b;
private float volume;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial3);


   // AudioManager audio settings for adjusting the volume
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // Current volumn Index of particular stream type.
    float currentVolumeIndex = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(streamType);

    // Get the maximum volume index for a particular stream type.
    float maxVolumeIndex = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(streamType);

    // Volumn (0 --> 1)
    //this.volume = currentVolumeIndex / maxVolumeIndex;
    volume = currentVolumeIndex / maxVolumeIndex;

    // Suggests an audio stream whose volume should be changed by
    // the hardware volume controls.
    //this.setVolumeControlStream(streamType);
    setVolumeControlStream(streamType);

    // For Android SDK >= 21
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

        AudioAttributes audioAttrib = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        SoundPool.Builder builder = new SoundPool.Builder();
        builder.setAudioAttributes(audioAttrib).setMaxStreams(MAX_STREAMS);

        this.soundPool = builder.build();
    }
    // for Android SDK < 21
    else {
        // SoundPool(int maxStreams, int streamType, int srcQuality)
        this.soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    // When Sound Pool load complete.
    this.soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });

    // Load sound file (destroy.wav) into SoundPool.
    soundId1k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.one_kecik, 1);

    // Load sound file (gun.wav) into SoundPool.
    soundId2k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.two_kecik, 1);

    soundId3k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.three_kecik, 1);

    soundId5k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.five_kecik, 1);

    soundId6k = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.six_kecik, 1);

    soundId6b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.six_besar, 1);

    soundId5b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.five_besar, 1);

    soundId3b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.three_besar, 1);

    soundId2b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.two_besar, 1);

    soundId1b = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.one_besar, 1);




    final ImageButton btnCells[] = new ImageButton[14];

    int refid[] = {R.id.btn12, R.id.btn02,R.id.btn11,R.id.btn03,R.id.btn10,R.id.btn04,R.id.btn10,R.id.btn04,R.id.btn11,R.id.btn03,R.id.btn12,R.id.btn02,R.id.btn10,R.id.btn04};


    for (int j = 0; j < refid.length; j++) {
        final int b = j;
        btnCells[b] = (ImageButton) findViewById(refid[b]); // Fetch the view id from array
        //final int finalJ = j;

        //View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        btnCells[b].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (v.equals(btnCells[0])) {
                    count1 = 1;
                   returnsound3k();


                }
                if (v.equals(btnCells[1])) {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound3b();

                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[2]))
                {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound2k();


                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[3])){
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound2b();
                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[4]))
                {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound1k();
                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[5]))
                {
                    count1 = 1;
                   returnsound1b();

                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[6]))
                {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound1k();
                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[7]))
                {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound1b();
                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[8])) {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound2k();

                }
                if (v.equals(btnCells[9])) {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound2b();
                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[10]))
                {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound3k();
                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[11])){
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound3b();
                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[12]))
                {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound1k();
                }

                if (v.equals(btnCells[13]))
                {
                    count1 = 1;
                    returnsound1b();
                }



                sum1 += count1;
                correct = sum1;

            }




        });
    }


    }





public int returnsound1k ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId1k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound2k ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId2k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound3k ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId3k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound5k ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId5k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound6k ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId6k, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound6b ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId6b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound5b ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId5b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound3b ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId3b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound2b ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId2b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}

public int returnsound1b ()
{

    if (loaded) {
        float leftVolumn = volume;
        float rightVolumn = volume;
        // Play sound of gunfire. Returns the ID of the new stream.
        streamIdd = soundPool.play(soundId1b, leftVolumn, rightVolumn, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    return streamIdd;
}





    public void chkmarks(View view) {
    checkmark = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chkmark);


    checkmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder altdial = new AlertDialog.Builder(tutorial3.this);
            altdial.setMessage("you scored " + correct + " out of 14!").setCancelable(true)

                    .setNegativeButton("play now!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(tutorial3.this, play.class));
                        }
                    })


                    .setPositiveButton("home", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //dialog.cancel();
                            startActivity(new Intent(tutorial3.this, menu.class));
                        }


                    });


            AlertDialog alert = altdial.create();
            alert.setTitle("Marks");
            alert.show();


        }


    });


}
```

}